# SQL Shift Timeseries (Get Following Row For Multiple Timestamps)

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count, window-functions

I have a database which looks like this:

```
timestamp           | entity_id
--------------------+----------
2021-12-01 10:00:00 | A
2021-12-01 09:00:00 | A
2021-12-01 08:00:01 | A
2021-12-01 08:00:00 | B
2021-12-01 07:00:00 | A
```

`timestamp` is `UNIQUE`, but I don't know in advance how far different timestamps are apart. How can I write a statement that would get me the following result?

```
entity_id | following_entity_id | count
----------+---------------------+------
A         | A                   | 2
A         | B                   | 1
B         | A                   | 1
```

When using pandas I'd probably use its `shift` method, but I need to do this using raw SQL in this case.

Comment: Do you want the following or the previous entity_id (by the order of timestamps)? Also, you posted only 4 rows as sample data. If there is another couple of As later in the table would this also count in the results of the 1st row?

Comment: I want the `entity_ids` which immediately follow the entity chronologically over the entire table -- did I understand your question correctly? Note also that the timestamps in my sample data are all 1h apart, in my real data this doesn't have to be the case. PS: I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The A of "2021-12-01 10:00:00 | A" is the last entity_id and has no following entity_id (meaning there is nothing after that chronologically). The A of "2021-12-01 08:00:01 | A" has the A of "2021-12-01 10:00:00 | A" as following entity_id. The B of "2021-12-01 08:00:00 | B" has the A of "2021-12-01 08:00:01 as following entity_id and so on. Is this that you want?

Comment: Yes, and then I assume I cam `GROUP BY following_entity_id` and `COUNT(*)` to get a result like shown in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `LAG()` window function to get the value of the previous (chronologically) `entity_id` (or `LEAD()` window function to get the following) and then aggregate:

```
SELECT entity_id, following_entity_id, COUNT(*) count
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(entity_id) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) following_entity_id
  FROM tablename       
)
WHERE following_entity_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY entity_id, following_entity_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3e2455a61645a697b0b1a56687c1695a).